# Should I implement both Callable and Runnable here?

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp

I'm creating a TCP client to send and receive basic bytes with another host on the network (it's just the two machines).

My understanding is that I will need a thread for receiving which continuously reads the incoming stuff into a queue, and a separate thread for sending stuff. So I can send a second message without waiting for reply to the first message.

Assuming I do it that way, I want the main thread to be popping messages off this queue and processing them to work out what reply to send. My understanding is that this would require Callable in order to return the messages to the main thread. But I also need Runnable to fill the queue up.

Do I need both?

e.g.

```java
public class TcpClient implements Runnable, Callable {
    
    ...

    @Override
    public void run() {
       while (true) {
           // read a message
           // add to queue
       }
    }

    @Override 
    public MyMessage call() {
        // pop a message off the queue
        // return message
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you so sure that you need multiple threads? You said, "...a TCP _client._" The simplest clients communicate _synchronously_ with their server: Send a message, then await a reply. Maybe send another message, and then await that reply, etc. You only need a single thread for that.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding that you need 2 threads is (partly) correct. It's not the only way to do it, but it is a common way. More generally that common way is:

- You have one thread that asks a `ServerSocket` object for the next Socket. This represents a server listening to connections on a port, e.g. a webserver listens on port 443 for connections, and, naturally, can handle more than one simultaneously, which means there's a dedicated thread whose one and only job is to 'pick up' anytime anybody connects. It can't do the job of actually dealing with the connection because that would imply it can't 'pick up the phone' anymore while it is doing that. This thread, once it 'picks up' (has a Socket object), fires off threads to handle that socket and then gets immediately back to asking the ServerSocket for the next Socket (back to being able to pick up the phone). Think one of those clichéd 'Hello, this is the assistent at Introdyne Corp, may I redirect you?' phone operators at a company who is just picking up, redirecting the call, and picking up another call endlessly.
- Each such 'job' is generally spun off to a handler which itself does all the work in 2 threads: One to receive, one to send. You *can* use a single thread but then you have monoplexed comm lines: If you 'send' a message to the other side and expect a response, you have to wait until that response comes in, and once a response has come in, you go back to sending something. It can't work unless [A] you have no need to ever interrupt, [B] you have no need to send and receive simultaneously, *and* [C] you always know which party is the next in line to send. For example, if you set up a connection solely to send a file, you could monoplex it - because all that happens is that the file sender sends a size, then sends that many bytes, then receives an acknowledgement 'okay, I received that data and wrote that', and then loops around until the file is done. That fits the rules and could be done in one thread.

You do not need to be a Callable to 'return messages to the main thread', in fact, that makes no sense at all.

In basis, if 2 threads both interact with a field, **then your code is broken** unless you are *very* careful about how you do that access - JVMs may or may not create local-to-the-CPU-core cached for any field, which is why it's so broken: One day each thread is just writing to its own local copy, the next day they don't. It's not testable.

So, think *very carefully* about inter-thread comms. You need to write either code that guards this carefully (e.g. by doing **all** access, both reads and writes, via `synchronized` blocks), or you use a different abstraction (databases, for example), or you use a data type designed to do this, such as a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` - the `java.util.concurrent` package is a trove of useful stuff designed for stuff like this, and it's what I suggest you do.

Some thread puts 'jobs' in such a queue, and other threads pull jobs off of this queue. Results are processed in a different queue - those connection threads put jobs in the queue (call `.offer()` on a shared object), and 'handle the result' threads pull (call `.poll()` or similar on that same shared object) results off of it.

Comment: Given me lots to think about, thanks